# How to make slideshows work on mobile devices browsers?

Tags: views

I created a view formatted slideshow using [Views Slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow)
and another formatted flexslider using [Flex Slider](https://www.drupal.org/project/flexslider).

But the two blocks show no content when displaying the page from a mobile device.

What's wrong (with flexslider as it support mobile) or how to make the slideshow work for mobile using one of the two modules listed?

Answer (score 1):

Download the FlexSlider library from https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider

Put the folder in a libraries directory sites/all/libraries and also

Try installing the [FlexSlider Views Slideshow](https://drupal.org/project/flexslider_views_slideshow) module which integration with Views Slideshow and FlexSlider

> This is the FlexSlider Views Slideshow module which used to be
>   included in FlexSlider by default.

This [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s8I0r6zEvjI) shows you how to create a responsive slideshow using the Views Slideshow module and jQuery FlexSlider.